# How to approve/reject other user edited answer/question?

Tags: support, questions, suggested-edits

When I edit some one question/answer then other user see this edit & they have right to approve/reject my edited review.

I also want approve/reject other user edited review.
How can do this?
Is there mechanism/process to  earn the privilege approve/reject other user question/Answer?